# a neural network can be used as an optimizer?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I was wondering if a neural network can be used as an optimizer.
In other words, a network2 used as an optimizer takes the loss value of network1 and based on that it predicts the best weights for network 1.
as a discriminator in architecture, gan imitates a function of loss.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - That is called [learning to learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06072). One neural network learns to do on-line updates of the parameters of another neural network. Long Short Term Memory (LSTM) are the most frequently used architecture.

Answer (score 0):

**Theoretically yes, pratically no.**

just think About what you Need for this second Network. You Need a dataset X of real numbers representing loss and you Need y representing weight plus bias.

You can already see that weights of a slightly different Architecture will be different. So creating such dataset is just infeasable given that you Need a lot of datapoints for your Network to learn.